# need help to center my navbar links, since adding searchbar on the right side. anyone?

Tags: html, css, navbar

i had my links nicely in the center under my logo
now i added a searchbar and flaoted it at the right side cause i want it there 
only problem i got now is that i cant get my links centered anymore :-/
anyone knows a solution so i can still center my navbar links ?

```css
                           /*Topnav*/
.topnav { 
    width: 100%; 
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0; 
 border-bottom: dotted #66A761;
 border-top: dotted #66A761;
}

.topnav ul {
    text-align: center;
}

.topnav ul li {
    display: inline; 
    margin-left: 15px; 
}

.topnav a {
    font-size: 20px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
}

.topnav a:link {
    color :#9F257D;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    color: #66A761;
}

.topnav input {
 float: right;
 padding: 3px;
 margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
                           <!--Topnav-->
<div class="topnav">
 <nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="aboutblank.html">recepten</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">varianten</a></li>
  <li><a href="aboutblank.html">contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="aboutblank.html">over ons</a></li>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
 </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following change over css

```css
    .topnav input {
      float: right;
      padding: 3px;
      margin: 0 5px;
      position: absolute; //input will hover on the navbar
      right: 20px; //this gives a bit of padding to the right
    }
    .topnav {
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 1;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding: 5px 0px 5px 0;
      border-bottom: dotted #66A761;
      border-top: dotted #66A761;
      position:relative; //this allows the navbar to be the anchor to child elements with position absolute
    }
```

The nav buttons are not being centered as the position for the search bar was static, so if you set it as **absolute** it will float over your navbar. Notice that you have to change the **navbar to position relative** because you want the search bar to be anchored to that element.

HTML:

```
<div class="topnav">
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">recepten</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">varianten</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutblank.html">over ons</a></li>
        <input type="text" style="right:0" placeholder="Search..">
    </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thnx allot ! learned something again gotta keep this one in mind ! THNX